# Where did the naming structure of particles come from (suffix -on)?

Tags: terminology, naming-conventions, particle-physics

I was looking at a list of particles, and I noticed that many of them ended in **-on**.  Prot*on*, electr*on*, neutr*on*, lept*on*, etc. Is there a historical (or linguistic) reason behind this naming structure?

Comment: I suppose you could add in elements here, with all the *-ium*s.

Comment: See [here](http://www.chemteam.info/Chem-History/Stoney-1894.html) for the letter of [George Johnstone Stoney](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Johnstone_Stoney)

Comment: See also [here](http://works.bepress.com/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1016&context=marianina_olcott) for Greek etymology

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a question about etymology. It all started with the genuine Greek words anion “going up” and kation “going down”, both neuter participles of the verb “to go” with different preverbs: an(a)- and kat(a)-. Then we got “ion” on its own as a term encompassing both, and then, by analogy, “proton”, “electron”, “neutron”, and ultimately also “positron” (based on a spurious reanalysis of electr-on as elect-ron, and creation of a pseudo-suffix “ron”.)

Comment: I think the essence of this answer is the following. Particles were named after Greek words, and this was done in a gender-neutral fashion, rendering -on the only possible suffix.

Comment: Not all neuter nouns/adjectives in Greek end in -on.

Comment: ...but it's the canonical example, IIRC from Greek in school (it was a while ago...)

Comment: I think the pseudo-suffix should be "tron"